# how to create a Richfaces/JSF Dynamic Accordion?

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, richfaces, accordion

I want to create a dynamic Accordion, My usecase is like, On every click of a Action button I want to add 1 Accordion Item. 


I am using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 4.1.0 Final

Pls help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to maintain a list of items in your managed bean. Then you could use a4j:repeat to iterate over this list in your jsf page and create a rich:accordionItem for each of element in the list. The action method for the button could add items to the list on the bean.